# How is ambiguity in selecting from overloaded methods resolved in Java?

Tags: java

```
package org.study.algos;
public class Study {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       A a = new A();
       a.m1(null);
    }
 }
 class A {
    public void m1(String s) {
       System.out.println("String");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    public void m1(Object obj) {
       System.out.println("Object");
       System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Here, the output is

> String
>   null

Why does the JVM resolve the method to one with a String argument?

Thanks in advance 
J

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545501/which-overload-will-get-selected-for-null-in-java

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a fairly elaborate algorithm, detailed in [JLS 15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).  But the part that is relevant here is [15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2), which says "the most specific one is chosen."  Both the Object and String overloads are "accessible and applicable" (the String is applicable because a null literal is a reference of all types), and the String is more specific.

EDIT: Corrected section, per Syntactic.

Comment: I think you want 15.12.2. 15.11.2 is about accessing superclass members with the super keyword.

Comment: how can i call the least specific method ?? if i have foo(Object o); and foo(String s);. and i want to call foo(Object o). what do i do ?

Comment: @SagarNayak Old comment, but I'll answer for future visitors. A cast does it: foo((Object) "hi") would call the Object version of foo.

Answer (score 10):

These methods are "overloaded", not "ambiguous".

According to the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.9):

> When a method is invoked (§15.12), the
>   number of actual arguments (and any
>   explicit type arguments) and the
>   compile-time types of the arguments
>   are used, at compile time, to
>   determine the signature of the method
>   that will be invoked (§15.12.2).

And §15.12.2 says:

> There may be more than one such
>   method, in which case the **most
>   specific one** is chosen.

`String` is more specific than `Object`, so while `null` is compatible with both, the method with the `String` parameter is chosen (there are much more complex rules that apply when the parameter types are part of a class or interface hierarchy).

Answer (score 2):

null value can be set to reference of any type.
All overloaded methods you have are in one inheritance hierarchy Object <- String, the least general one is being choosen.
But if you had two overloaded methods that are not in the same hierarchy, then you'd get compilation error about ambigous methods.

Answer (score 0):

A String is an Object, an Object is not a String, thus the first overload is **more specific** than the second. See [JLS 15.12.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2), as Syntactic mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question. Jon Skeet wrote a big answer.

The link to my question: [Which overload will get selected for null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545501/which-overload-will-get-selected-for-null-in-java)