# Something interesting about two overloaded constructors of FileInputStream in Java 7 API

Tags: java, constructor-overloading

Before talking about FileInputStream, I am starting with a scenario where there are two perfectly valid, overloaded methods but where the compiler will get confused and then report a compile-time error in response to certain inputs.

Here are the methods.

```
double calcAverage(double marks1, int marks2) {  
   return (marks1 + marks2)/2.0;  
}  

double calcAverage(int marks1, double marks2) {  
   return (marks1 + marks2)/2.0;  
}
```

Here is the complete code showing the use of the methods:

```
class MyClass {  
  double calcAverage(double marks1, int marks2) {  
            return (marks1 + marks2)/2.0;  
  }  
  double calcAverage(int marks1, double marks2) {  
           return (marks1 + marks2)/2.0;  
  }  
  public static void main(String args[]) {  
          MyClass myClass = new MyClass();  
          myClass.calcAverage(2, 3);  
  }  
}
```

Because an int literal value can be passed to a variable of type double, both methods are acceptable candidates for literal values **2** and **3**, and therefore the compiler fails to decide which method to pick.

This is where I get confused when I take the above concept with me, dive further into the Java 7 API to the FileInputStream class, and study about two overloaded constructors of that class.

1. public FileInputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {.....}
2. public FileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {.....}

According to the Java 7 API source code, the definition of the version that takes a String object as the argument is:

```
public FileInputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {  
       this(name != null ? new File(name) : null);  
}
```

Now, if "**name**" is indeed null, **this(name != null ? new File(name) : null);** evaluates to **this(null);** which in turn is equivalent to invocation of **FileInputStream(null);** but then both **FileInputStream(String)** and **FileInputStream(File)** become possible choices to be invoked with a null value. Does it not give rise to ambiguity? So, isn't there a compile-time error for that?

I do understand that eventually a FileNotFoundException is raised, but it is a separate issue which comes later. How is the ambiguity resolved before that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is ambiguity in selecting from overloaded methods resolved in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608394/how-is-ambiguity-in-selecting-from-overloaded-methods-resolved-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which overload will get selected for null in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545501/which-overload-will-get-selected-for-null-in-java)

Comment: No, it is not duplicate. I have just now visited that link. There the scenario is different since on that topic there is a hierarchical relation between the classes involved. But here, the classes String and File are unrelated.

Comment: In the possible duplicates said that the most concrete class is to be chosen between Object and String... but in this case both (String and File) extends Object so... I think the question is not duplicated.

Comment: The issue here is the return type of the ternary conditional operator `a ? b : c`, which is in this case `java.io.File`, so there is no ambiguity. The question is not a duplicate of either of the suggestions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your error is here:

> Now, if "name" is indeed null, `this(name != null ? new File(name) : null);` evaluates to `this(null);` which in turn is equivalent to invocation of `FileInputStream(null);`

It actually evaluates to `this((File) null)` -- that is, a null value explicitly typed as `File`. This is because the expression `name != null ? new File(name) : null` has to have a type, and that type is the most specific type of the two alternatives. In this case, one alternative is typed as `File` and the other is typed as `null`, so the most specific common type is `File`.

That's why it's able to unambiguously resolve it to the `FileInputStream(File)` constructor. It's analogous to:

```
File file = null;
new FileInputStream(file);
```

Comment: Why do you say that it evaluates to this((File)null) ?
According to the concise "if" statement, the outcome is either this(new File(name)) or this(null)

Comment: @mth's answer describes why

Comment: @MohammadAliAsgar It's important to understand that the `? ... :` bit isn't A shortcut for a statement, it's an _expression_. All expressions have a type. For instance, you can't call a method that returns `void` using `?`.

Comment: Yes, I have got it now. Excellent. Thanks to everyone, especially yshavit, mth, and Erwin Bolwidt

Comment: When you say "most specific type", don't you mean "most specific common supertype"? That is, since null is a subtype of File, it is more specific than File, and the most specific of the two alternatives.

Comment: Except that `null` isn't actually a subtype of `File`, or of anything else for that matter. It's handled specially. `null instanceof File` is `false`.

Answer (score 15):

The type of the result of the conditional operator is `File`. 
The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-300-C) defines:

> If one of the second and third operands is of the null type and the type of the other is a reference type, then the type of the conditional expression is that reference type.

So there is no ambiguity about which constructor should be called