# What would be the output of following program(method overloading)

Tags: java

I have following program with method overloading.
Can someone please explain me the output of following program.

```
public class test {

    public void display(Object obj)
    {
        System.out.println("object method");
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
    public void display(String str)
    {
        System.out.println("String method");
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test t=new test();
        t.display(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you wish to test small bits of code like this, try [compilejava.net](http://compilejava.net) and it correctly shows it uses the String method

Comment: This answers why display(String) is getting called rather than display(Object) if that's what you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608394/how-is-ambiguity-in-selecting-from-overloaded-methods-resolved-in-java

Answer (score 2):

The least *generic* (*most specific*) constructor will be called. So, `public void display(String str)` will be called and hence `String method` followed by `null` will be printed

Object class is at the top of the hierarchy of classes. `String`, `StringBuilder`,  `Exception` etc are at 1 level below `Object`. `IOException` is one level below `Exception`. So, if you have 3 methods one taking `Object`, another `Exception` and another `IOException`, the method with `IOException` will be called, since it is at the lowest level in the class hierarchy (*least generic*).

Try putting 2 classes which are at the same level and see what happens :)

Comment: "least non-generic" Could you elaborate or provide a link to some documentation that describes this further?

Comment: Can you please elaborate it in more simple word

Comment: @Arc676 - Done. Check my edit. I am sure java docs do cover this somewhere. My bad. There was a typo there. It should be *least generic* (*more specific*)

Comment: @user2085714 - Check my edit

Comment: "Try putting 2 classes which are at the same level and see what happens" Challenge accepted :) ..tomorrow