# Why and How Does This Java Code Compile?

Tags: java

The following code prints "String"

```
public class Riddle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hello(null);
    }

    public static void hello(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }


    public static void hello(String s) {
        System.out.println("String");
    }

}
```

Why does that code compile? Isn't *null* ambiguous?

For example, the following code will NOT compile because of an ambiguous signature.

```
public class Riddle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hello(null);
    }

    public static void hello(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public static void hello(Integer o) {
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }

    public static void hello(String s) {
        System.out.println("String");
    }

}
```

Can someone please explain why the first example can compile without having ambiguous errors?

Comment: The `null` is just a parameter.  In the second case, the `Object` method signature cannot be resolved against the other two.

Comment: Congratulations, I think you've found one of the actual holes in Java's Type Theory. In general, "Null" is kind of a weird creature to type systems. If you're interested in this, you might check out the Option type that some languages use... I personally think it's a really good feature, and wish it weren't too late to bring it into Java.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608394/how-is-ambiguity-in-selecting-from-overloaded-methods-resolved-in-java or also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545501/which-overload-will-get-selected-for-null-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case doesn't compile as  the compiler can't decide between the method that takes an Integer and the method that takes a String, where as in case of first the compiler can figure it out.

Reference : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2

Answer (score 0):

please, see JLS [§15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

> following order of method resolving for calling purpose is important
>   when same type data-type is there,
>
> 1. (for primitive data-type)exact data-type match then call it.
>      1.1 if not then call to broader then this data-type available then call it.
> 2. match for Wrapper type of Data-type or parent of it if above failed then.
> 3. Vararg of this data-type will match if above 2-failed.