# Java: selection between overloaded constructors

Tags: java, compiler-errors, ambiguous-call

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608394/how-is-ambiguity-in-selecting-from-overloaded-methods-resolved-in-java), Java will select the "most specific" option when trying to select between ambiguous overloaded constructors.  In this example:

```
public class Test{
    private Test(Map map){
        System.out.println("Map");
    }
    private Test(Object o){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test(null);
    }
}
```

it will print

> "Map"

However, I was trying to figure out exactly what "most specific" means. I assumed it meant "least ambiguous", as in "may refer to the fewest possible types."  In this context, `Object` may be anything that isn't a primitive, while `Map` may only be `Map` or `? extends Map`.  Basically, I assumed that whichever class was closer to the leaf of the inheritance tree would be selected.  That works when one class is a subclass of the other:

```
public class Test{
    private Test(A a){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    private Test(B b){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test(null);
    }
}

class A{}

class B extends A{}
```

> "B"

Then I came up with this:

```
public class Test{
    private Test(A a){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    private Test(E e){
        System.out.println("E");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test(null);
    }
}

class A{}

class B extends A{}

class C{}

class D extends C{}

class E extends D{}
```

I would think it should print `E`, as `E` may only refer to one known type, whereas `A` may refer to two (`A` and `B`).  But it give an ambiguous reference error.

How is it actually choosing the constructor?  I read through [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) but frankly I couldn't quite follow how it determines specificity.  I'm hoping for a description of exactly why it can't determine that `E` is more specific than `A`.

Comment: nothing can be this: ***? extends String***, string class is final

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ good point. I'll fix that

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's not based on the number of types that are convertible to the parameter type - it's whether any value that's valid for one overload is valid for another, due to implicit conversions.

For example, there's an implicit conversion from `String` to `Object`, but the reverse isn't true, so `String` is more specific than `Object`.

Likewise there's an implicit conversion from `B` to `A`, but the reverse isn't true, so `B` is more specific than `A`.

With `A` and `E` however, neither is more specific than the other - there no conversion from `A` to `E`, and no conversion from `E` to `A`. That's why overload resolution fails.

The relevant bit of the JLS is actually [15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), which includes this that might make it easier for you to understand:

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

So if you have:

```
void foo(String x)
void foo(Object x)
```

every invocation handled by `foo(String)` could be handled by `foo(Object)`, but the reverse is not the case. (For example, you could call `foo(new Object())` and that couldn't be handled by `foo(String)`.)

Comment: That quote is what I was looking for.  I guess I didn't read that far.

Comment: Do you happen to know how "complex" (choose whatever metric you want) Java's overload resolution is? E.g. C♯'s overload resolution is in NP, in fact, you can encode any 3-SAT problem in a set of overloads and have the compiler solve it for you.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I don't know at all, I'm afraid :(

Comment: how can i call the least specific method ?? if i have foo(Object o); and foo(String s);. and i want to call foo(Object o). what do i do ?

Comment: @SagarNayak: Cast the argument to `Object` so that `foo(String)` isn't applicable.

Answer (score 9):

Following statement of the [JSL§15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) answers that,

> The informal intuition is that one method is **more specific** than
>   another *if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time error.*

**Case 1**

- You can pass anything in constructor which takes `Object` while we can not pass anything other than a `Map` in first constructor. So whatever I pass in `Map` constructor can be handled by `Object` constructor and that's why `Test(Map map)` becomes mote specific.

**Case 2**

- Since `B` extends `A`, here `Test(B b)` constructor becomes more specific. As we can pass `B` in `Test(A a)` thanks to *inheritance*.

**Case 3**

- In this case there is no direct conversion to depict the more specific method and it results in *ambiguity*.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is because E is not more specific than A, as they belong to different hierarchies they cannot be compared. Thus, when you pass a null, Java cannot know which hierarchy to use.