# Does null have Object type?

Tags: java

Why does this output: "inside String argument method"? Isn't null "Object" type?

```
class A {
    void printVal(String obj) {
        System.out.println("inside String argument method");
    }

    void printVal(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("inside Object argument method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.printVal(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow crazy. I just tried adding a third `printVal` overload, `printVal(Integer obj)` to see what would happen. Now `a.printVal(null)` is a compiler error, due to ambiguity. Good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but null is also String type and all other types, so it selects the most specific method to call.

Answer (score 8):

The most specific matching method will be called.  More information here:

- [Which overload will get selected for null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545501/which-overload-will-get-selected-for-null-in-java#1545512)

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, a `null` **literal** will call the String version, for the reasons outlined by the other answers.

On the other hand:

```
class A {
    void printVal(String obj) {
        System.out.println("inside String argument method");
    }

    void printVal(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("inside Object argument method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        Object myObj = null;
        a.printVal(myObj);
    }
}
```

will print "inside Object argument method."  As will settings the type for `myObj` to any type other than `String`.