# Why is String Object Instantiation a bad practice?

Tags: java, string

Why this statement is bad practice :

```
String colour= new String("Blue");
```

and what's difference with this statement

```
String colour="Blue";
```

Comment: Possibly related: [String object instantiation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16742819).

Comment: *"Why this statement is bad practice"* - One reason is that it is pointless.  Just like comments in your code about your favourite colour is.

Comment: This is because of the immutability of String. For more information have a look at this tutorial http://www.javahelps.com/2015/03/immutability-of-string.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is discouraged because it reads a `String` from the `String` intern pool and then instantiates a new object instance. The Wikipedia article on [String interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) says (in part)

> In computer science, **string interning** is a method of storing only one copy of each distinct string value, which must be immutable. Interning strings makes some string processing tasks more time- or space-efficient at the cost of requiring more time when the string is created or interned. The distinct values are stored in a **string intern pool**.

The second example assigns a reference to the `String` from the intern pool.

Comment: Won't the compiler optimize it so they run the same?

Comment: @MrMadsen No. You'd get a new object reference. `"Blue" != new String("Blue")`

Comment: Indeed, the JLS >>guarantees<< that it will be a new object reference ... if there is any possibility that you can observe this.  (And testing using `!=` is one way to observe it ...)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an unnecessary String object.

```
String colour= new String("Blue");
```

"Blue" is already a String type.