# Polymorphism and method overloading

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

I have a quick and straighforward question:

I have this simple class:

```
public class A
{
    public void m(Object o)
    {
      System.out.println("m with Object called");
    }

    public void m(Number n)
    {
       System.out.println("m with Number called");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       A a = new A();
       // why will m(Number) be called?
       a.m(null);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: actually is method with Number actually being called. Sorry about the confusion.

If I call a.m(null) it calls method with Number parameter.

My question is: why is this? where in the java language specification is this specified?

Comment: ... because `null` is not a `Number` object, thus it falls into the more generalized `Object` bucket.

Comment: that's funny because on my machine (running it on eclipse) it alwways defaults to the Number method

Comment: -1 this is overloading, not overriding

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, it actually calls `m(Number)`.

It happens because both methods are *applicable*, but `m(Number)` is *the most specific* method, since any argument of `m(Number)` can be passed to `m(Object)`, but not vice versa.

If you replace `m(Object)` by `m(String)` (or add another method such as `m(Date)`), compiler would report ambiguity, since the most specific method can't be identified.

See the section [Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301183) in the Java Specification.

Comment: ok, now that I've actually run the example code, I see this too.  It also makes sense that once I added m(Date n){...} that I got an error: "method m(Object) is ambiguous for the type"

Answer (score 12):

1. This is not polymorphism or overriding. This is method **overloading**.
2. I tested this and specific method is being called (not the m(Object)) and according to the spec the specific method is always called. [Which overload will get selected for null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545501/which-overload-will-get-selected-for-null-in-java#1545512)

Comment: +1 for noting the difference between overriding and overloading

Answer (score 8):

another related question for you to think about:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   A a = new A();
   Object n = new Integer(1);
   a.m(n); // which method will be called?
}
```

Comment: "m with Object called" will be called but i don't know why. Can anyone explain? Intuitively, I thought "m with Number called" will be printed, but... noooooo.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents. Method with Number argument is the one that is called, Because Number extends Object. I had a similar situation in the past, I did override a method and put Component instead of JComponent (by mistake).  It took me one week to find out the reason why my method was never called. I figure it out, that if there are some inheritance relationship between the overloaded methods, the JVM matches first the deeper one in the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is the default type in Java. If you refactor your `m(Object o)` method to `m(String o)` you'll have a compile time error saying that the call `m(null)` is ambiguous because Java cannot determine which class between `String` and `Number` defaults to `null`

Other than that, between `m(Object o)` and `m(Number o)`, calling `m(null)` will call `m(Number o)` because it's the most specialized method. You would need to cast `null` into an `Object` (or anything not an instance of `Number`) otherwise.

```
a.m((String) null);
```

Comment: null has no type and it calles m(Number)

Comment: well... formally there is a null type, and it's a subtype of all reference types. pretty weird.