# Java - passing null as an argument to print()

Tags: java, reference, outputstream

I want to know why the below code doesn't work :

```
System.out.print(null);    
response.getWriter().print(null);
```

But the below ones work :

```
String s = null;
System.out.print(s);
response.getWriter().print(s);
```

Whats the difference between passing a `null` as compared to passing a reference as `null` ?

**EDITED :**  Doesn't work fore mentioned indicates to compilation error .

Comment: Define "doesn't work."

Comment: Interesting. I suppose that just passing a `null` makes it so that the program treats it as nothing while passing a `null` through a reference works since it's basically showing that the variable itself has no value.

Comment: the initial null isnt bound to an object. The second is a string which contains null data. Likely this would return the same as "" which would be accepted by the compiler fine

Comment: "Doesn't work" == "Doesn't compile" or "Doesn't work" == "Does not run"?

Comment: @RyanS an empty string is decidedly different from a null string.

Comment: The System.out.println(someObjectRefrence) actually invokes toString() method and in-case your passed reference does not override one, The default implementation of Object class is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers . From your inputs , I compiled the answer myself . It seems the call `System.out.print(null)` is ambiguous to compiler because `print(null)` here will find the two best specific matches i.e. `print(String)` and `print(char[])` . So compiler is unable to determine which method to call here .
Small example will be :

```
private void methodCall(String str) {
}

private void methodCall(char[] ch){
}
```

Now this code becomes ambigious : `methodCall(null)` .

Answer (score 9):

This is because you can pass an `Object` or a `String`. Since `null` can fit in both, the compiler doesn't know which method to use, leading to compile error.

Methods definitions:

- [System.out.print(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.Object))
- [System.out.print(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String))

Instead, if you provide an `Object` or a `String` variable (even if it has `null` value), the compiler would know which method to use.

EDIT: This is better explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4960961/1065197). As to the internal link pointing to the Java specification, you can read it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), and this case would suit here:

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another **if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.
>
> It is possible that no method is the most specific, because there are two or more methods that are maximally specific.

Comment: This is called "overloading"

Comment: I don't think that it's that it could be either, but it's not either. `System.out.println()` expects something non-null.

Comment: @Raufio if you test the 2nd code block provided by OP (without the `response...` part), in a simple `public static void main(String[] args)` method, the program will print *null* and terminate with no problems.

Comment: @Luiggi: Is it really that ambiguous for the compiler ? Since null is a defined keyword in Java , designers of the compiler know that if its null they have to print null , doesn't matter whether its a String reference or Object reference ! Null is Class agnostic !!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah, because it is a `null` string, not just `null`. If you cast `null` to anything else it will work.

Comment: @noob yeah, but as explained in Raufio's answer, `null` doesn't have a type, it could be a `String`, an `Object` or anything else that's not a primitive, so it leads to confusion to the compiler

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's for a deeper understanding about how the error occurs, not just the surface level of it.

Comment: @Luigi : print(String) is more specific method in the above case . I have raised a similar question earlier :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361639/java-method-overloading-and-choosing-the-most-specific-type . I don't understand where is the ambiguity in choosing a more specific method here ?

Answer (score 3):

It's because `System.out.println()` expects something with a type. `null` doesn't have a type, and therefore it can't be output on it's own. This is shown by:

Doesn't work:

```
 System.out.println(null);
```

Works:

```
 System.out.println((String)null);
 System.out.println((char[])null);
 System.out.println((Object)null);
```

It's the compiler type-checking the parameters of the method call.