# How does Java choose which constructor to use?

Tags: java

I am not able to understand the output of the following program.

```
public class Confusing {

    private Confusing(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    private Confusing(double[] dArray) {
        System.out.println("double array");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Confusing(null);
    }
}
```

The correct output is "double array". WHy was this constructor chosen as more specific than the other when both can accept null?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which overload will get selected for null in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545501/which-overload-will-get-selected-for-null-in-java)

Answer (score 18):

Even though both constructors can accept `null`, `double[]` *inherits* from `java.lang.Object`, and is therefore more specific.

Comment: @downvoter would you care to elaborate on what you think is wrong with the answer?

Comment: Maybe because of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resentment) (disclaimer: wasn't me)

Comment: I read this in Liskov's book "A method m1 is more specific than another method m2 if any legal call of m1 would also be a legal call of m2 if more conversions were done". This mean if there is a method comp(int) and comp(long), passing an int param will go to comp(int) (which is m1 above) as it could also go to comp(long) (which is m2 above) with conversion. But a vice versa does not hold as a comp cannot be passed to m1.    However, how can you apply this logic to a null param in my original question - it can be applied to both double[] and Object without conversion??

Comment: @user1614482 `int` and `long` are primitives, with conversion rules defined for them; unlike `Object` and `double[]`, neither one is a subclass of the other. When overloads use a single parameter related as base-subclass, the subclass wins when `null` is passed.

Answer (score 1):

> The challenge of compiling dynamically typed languages is how to implement a runtime system that can choose the most appropriate implementation of a method or function — after the program has been compiled. Treating all variables as objects of Object type would not work efficiently.

Hence, choosing the specific one over `Object`.