# Passing null reference in a method parameter in java?

Tags: java, string

When i run this code the output is "String"; if I hide the method that accepts a String parameter and run the code again then the output is "Object", so can anyone please explain me how this code works?

```
public class Example {

    static void method(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    static void method(String str) {
        System.out.println("String");
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        method(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: [JonSkeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has a good [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1545512/1828937) to this question

Answer (score 8):

Compiler will choose most specific method, in this case, String is a sub class of Object, so the method with String as argument will be invoked.

From [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than
>   another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time type error.