# The constructor Confusing(Object) is ambiguous

Tags: java

I need some help in understanding the concept. Please refer following example and how code shows different outputs?

**Scenario-1:** If I used `public Confusing(Object o){` this method signature then output is object, but if I used `public Confusing(StringBuffer sb){` String Buffer output is printing?

```
public class Confusing {
    public Confusing(Object o){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }
    public Confusing(StringBuffer sb){
        System.out.println("String Buffer");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Confusing(null);
    }
}
```

**Scenario-2:** If I used use `public Confusing(Object o){` this method signature then output is object, but if I used `public Confusing(double[] dArray){` then why output is Double Array?

```
    public class Confusing {
    public Confusing(Object o){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }
    public Confusing(double[] dArray){
        System.out.println("Double Array");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Confusing(null);
    }
}
```

**Scenario-3** If I used following code then why I'm getting following error? **How we can fixed this error?**

```
The constructor Confusing(Object) is ambiguous

public class Confusing {
    public Confusing(Object o){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }
    /*public Confusing(double[] dArray){
        System.out.println("Double Array");
    }*/
    public Confusing(String s){
        System.out.println("String");
    }
    public Confusing(StringBuffer sb){
        System.out.println("String Buffer");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Confusing(null);
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor Confusing(Object) is ambiguous
```

Kindly help me to understand the concept.

Comment: Your description of scenario 2 doesn't match the code. It would help if in each case you would just show the code you're running, without anything commented out. Also, it's best not to *try* to run code that doesn't compile. Don't wait to get an exception - just make sure the code compiles before you run it!

Comment: Simply help to understand the concept for 1st and 2nd scenario, I will update details for 3rd scenario

Comment: Even the first scenario is confusing, because you haven't shown the code.

Comment: Other possible duplicate is this: [Which overload will get selected for null in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1545501)

Comment: Hi Tom - Great link, you solved all my problems, cheers, Thanks, Kalpita