# I recently came across this code snippet . This code prints Hello as output. I don't know the reason Why?

Tags: java, object

I think this code should give Error. But it gives me Hello as Output.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(null);
    }

    public static void foo(String str){
        System.out.println("Hello");
   }

    public static void foo(Object o){
       System.out.println("Hi");
   }
}
```

Comment: Why you think it should give an error?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545501/which-overload-will-get-selected-for-null-in-java

Answer (score 3):

`String` is a nullable type, therefore your call to `foo(String)` can take place.

Additionally, the overload resolution rule states that the "most specific" type takes the precedence, hence the `string` overload is chosen.

Comment: You are right;) I was thinking in C#, in fact in java is not correct. I amend the answer.